# My Bluetooth speaker pairs with raspberry but when i connect it says Connection failed: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, bluetooth

My Bluetooth speaker pairs with raspberry but when i connect it says Connection failed: No such file or directory

Please let me know if there are any links which I can refer in order to resolve this issue.

### Hardware Spec

1. Raspberry Pi B+
2. Raspbian OS 1.9.2
3. Connected to monitor (HDMI)
4. Has a Bluetooth Adapter and Wireless Adapter.
5. Power supply (5V 1A)